# Best Practice To access couple of parameters in different classes

Tags: java, scala, design-patterns

I have this scenario; accepting a set of values from main method argument and which has to be used in multiple classes and multiple methods. Could you suggest, what is the best practice or design pattern needed to make these params available in the classes anything other than passing as method argument?

example:

There are args received from the main method like param1,param2,param3..param6
Now these params have to be used by other classes methods.

Comment: Your question would be a lot better if you just included your code. We'd need to know what those methods look like and what the data to be passed around is...

Comment: What *other* classes are you talking about? If they rely on some state originating from the application entry point they should be created from there, too, taking any information they need as constructor parameters. As the information seems to be defined from the beginning and thus being somewhat immutable, why call the same methods again and again with the same parameters?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Why would you not want to pass your parameters as ... well ... parameters???

Answer (score 1):

You have asked a very general question so I will give a very general answer.

1. Use some form of dependency injection-- you don't have to use a dedicated DI framework, I rarely do, often I have the main method contain no logic other than to wire up my objects, and then call a method on some driver class which has its whole world wired up.  It yields the same benefits for unit and integration testing as any DI framework does, and doesn't force the next developer to learn whatever idiosyncratic, poorly documented, and unmaintained DI framework you chose; instead you use Scala-- it's really quite powerful, more people should try it.
2. If you find methods and constructors taking the same sets of parameters repeatedly, then create a parameter class describing those parameters.
3. More than 2 parameters is too many for a method, 1 parameter is better than 2, and no parameters are best of all.

Lastly, read Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship, by Robert C. Martin-- it teaches what code should look like at the most basic level, and I think every programmer should be taught its concepts before they even hear the term "Design Patterns". How long should methods be?  How many arguments should methods take?  How should methods be named?  I have a really long method, how do I break it up?  How should classes be named and what should be in them?  etc.

Or you could just do something ghastly like use Scala implicit parameters everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing a collection of data
(in your example,
a group of six parameters),
it is a reasonable practice to create a class that contains the data
(in your example,
a class that contains the six parameters)
and pass an instance of that class instead of constantly passing the six parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice actually *is* passing them as arguments. 
If you don't want that, you are pretty much stuck with something like:

```
object Globals {
 var param1: String 
 var param2: String 
 // ...
}
```

But this is *really* icky. Don't do it.